# At what stage to process data with the API (vuex)?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I work with pagination in the store and has small question.

Example of information returned from the back:

```
{last_page: 5, current_page: 1, per_page: 10, total: 100, count: 100, url: 'xyz.com'}
```

The view to which I will transform this information :

```
{LastPage: 5, currentPage: 1} // other fields are not needed
```

I call an action, make a request to the api in it, and get the result from the back containing the fields I don't need. I have to process it. Where is it more correct to do this? Pass the full object to the mutation and already process it in the mutation, or do the mutation in such a way that it would require an already prepared object and, accordingly, process this object in the action, and then throw its "beautiful" version into the mutation?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into creating some models to handle situations like this.

In your model add the things you care about, like this:

```
export class PageData {
  constructor(dto = {}) {
    this.lastPage = dto.lastPage || '';
    this.currentPage = dto.currentPage || '',
  }
}

export default {
  PageData,
}
```

Then in your store import the model like this: `import {PageData} from './models.js'`

Then simply pass your backend data into your new model when you commit the mutation like this:

```
commit('setPageData', new PageData(dtoFromBackend))
```